# How to update checkbox value in database when it check/unchecked

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

First of all please pardon me for my english.

I am implementing application in codignator. I want functionality like on multiple check box check/uncheck the value in database has to be updated.

```
Message :<input type="checkbox" class="Notification" name="Message"  value="1" checked="checked">
Message :<input type="checkbox" class="Notification" name="Call"  value="2" checked="checked">
Message :<input type="checkbox" class="Notification" name="Alert"  value="3" checked="checked">
<input type="submit" class="Notification" value="Submit">
```

now if i unchecked this checkbox than in database it should be update like

```
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '0' WHERE notification_id=1 Or
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '0' WHERE notification_id=2 Or
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '0' WHERE notification_id=3
```

If i check all the checkbox than in database it should be updated like

```
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '1' WHERE notification_id=1 Or
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '1' WHERE notification_id=2 Or
UPDATE `user_notifications`SET `istype` = '1' WHERE notification_id=3
```

In simple I have 3 notification_id and for each i assign one check box. so on particular checkbox check/uncheck update query must have to trigger

Please guide me how to do it with model view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You can check with

```
$post['Message'] = empty($post['Message']) ? 0 : 1;
$post['call'] = empty($post['call']) ? 0 : 1;
$post['alert'] = empty($post['alert']) ? 0 : 1;
```

if its checked it will give value "1" and not it will give you "0"

Hope that's what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

you can get the checked check box values using their class name in jquery as following

```
var checkedVals = $('.Notification:checkbox:checked').map(function() {
return this.value;
}).get();
```

alert(checkedVals.join(","));

Now you have to use jquery-ajax ($.post)method to update the check box values.